# Write a function that creates a new list then selects data by quarter except the current quarter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set that pulls in 24 months of data from the day the script is ran using python that I group by quarters with the below code.

```
def quarter_selection(input_date):
    curr_mnth = input_date.month
    if curr_mnth % 3 == 1:
        end_qrtr = input_date.quarter - 2
    else:
        end_qrtr = input_date.quarter
    return end_qrtr

def quarter_helper(date_col):
    return 'Q' + str(pd.to_datetime(date_col).quarter) + ' ' + str(pd.to_datetime(date_col).year)
```

I now would like to modify the below code to pull quarterly data with one conditions. I have attempted to do this by creating a new list but now I'm stuck. What the below code provides is quarterly data by year. Is there any way to replace "2017" with a condition that Exclude the current quarter and pulls  the previous quarter.

```
New_list = ["Q" + str(x) + " 2017" for x in range(1, 5)]
```